# List of lists to JSON in order?

Tags: python, json, format

I've got this list of lists :

```
[['Edan Daniele', '12.61', '5.00', '9.22', '1.50', '60.39', '16.43', '21.60', '2.60', '35.81', '5.25.72', '3656'], 
['Lehi Poghos', '13.04', '4.53', '7.79', '1.55', '64.72', '18.74', '24.20', '2.40', '28.20', '6.50.76', '2696'], 
['Coos Kwesi', '13.75', '4.84', '10.12', '1.50', '68.44', '19.18', '30.85', '2.80', '33.88', '6.22.75', '2856'],
['Severi Eileifr', '13.43', '4.35', '8.64', '1.50', '66.06', '19.05', '24.89', '2.20', '33.48', '6.51.01', '2674']]
```

I want to put this info into a JSON format/file. It should go through 1 to 4 in ascending order depending on the last number of the list.

What would be the best way to do that?

Thanks for your time in advance! :)

Comment: Sort the list first.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new_dict = {}
for i, x in enumerate(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True), 1):
    new_dict[str(i)] = {}
    new_dict[str(i)][x[0]] = x[1:]

print(new_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{
    '1': {'Edan Daniele': ['12.61', '5.00', '9.22', '1.50', '60.39', '16.43', '21.60', '2.60', '35.81', '5.25.72', '3656']}, 
    '2': {'Coos Kwesi': ['13.75', '4.84', '10.12', '1.50', '68.44', '19.18', '30.85', '2.80', '33.88', '6.22.75', '2856']}, 
    '3': {'Lehi Poghos': ['13.04', '4.53', '7.79', '1.55', '64.72', '18.74', '24.20', '2.40', '28.20', '6.50.76', '2696']}, 
    '4': {'Severi Eileifr': ['13.43', '4.35', '8.64', '1.50', '66.06', '19.05', '24.89', '2.20', '33.48', '6.51.01', '2674']}
}
```

Comment: this is kinda hard to wrap my head around.
and even then, I cannot get the idea, this code makes a list of dicts?

Comment: @Robertas in this way do you need data?, or it need to remain the same list of lists ?

Comment: well , i need to create a JSON file from these lists and put them in ascending order. like :  {"1": {'Edan Daniele': ['12.61', '5.00', '9.22', '1.50', '60.39', '16.43', '21.60', '2.60', '35.81', '5.25.72', '3656']}, "2": {'Coos Kwesi': ['13.75', '4.84', '10.12', '1.50', '68.44', '19.18', '30.85', '2.80', '33.88', '6.22.75', '2856']}} etc

Comment: This is a bit too high for my level, I need to study/check your code, but it really works. Really thanks for your time and effort to help me:)

Comment: @Robertas you are welcome, if it helps can you mark this answer as `accepted` ? :)  have a nice day